# How to use Radio to calculate a sum in angular 4

Tags: angular

How is it possible to perform sum of items checked using radio button?

Is it possible to do in real time, with each click the value is updated?

```
 <tr>
                <td class="text-center lab">
                <label class="labl">
                <input type="radio" value="{{result.value}}" name="item[0]item" [(ngModel)]="vItem" />
                <input type="radio" value="{{result.value}}" name="item[0]item" [(ngModel)]="vItem" />
                </label>
                </td>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="text-center lab">
                <label class="labl">
                <input type="radio" value="{{result.value}}" name="item[1]item" [(ngModel)]="vItem" />
                <input type="radio" value="{{result.value}}" name="item[1]item" [(ngModel)]="vItem" />
                </label>
                </td>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="text-center lab">
                <label class="labl">
                <input type="radio" value="{{result.value}}" name="item[2]item" [(ngModel)]="vItem" />
                <input type="radio" value="{{result.value}}" name="item[2]item" [(ngModel)]="vItem" />
                </label>
                </td>
                <tr>


              OutPut= <p>Sum of items checked : ??? </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a function in your ts, on each click pass the value to the function and sum and assign to a variable

```
 <input type="radio" value="{{result.value}}" name="item[0]item" [(ngModel)]="vItem" (change)="calculateSum(vItem)" />
```

in TS

```
total : number;
calculateSum(val :any){
  total += +val;
}
```

Comment: I edited the post to better understand. I have written expressed.